# Right way to display the_author_meta fields?

Tags: php, wp-admin, user-meta, author-template

Is the following code an accepted method—-or is there a better one—-to display a list of author contact links? (Extra ones have been added to my user profile page).

```
<ul class="author-contact">
<?php
// Get user profile fields 
$email      = get_the_author_meta( 'email' ); 
$telephone  = get_the_author_meta( 'telephone' ); 
$twitter    = get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ); 
$instagram  = get_the_author_meta( 'instagram' ); 
$pinterest  = get_the_author_meta( 'pinterest' ); 
$linkedin   = get_the_author_meta( 'linkedin' ); 
?>

<?php if( ! empty( $email ) ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $email; ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( ! empty( $telephone ) ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $telephone; ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( ! empty( $twitter ) ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $twitter; ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( ! empty( $instagram ) ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $instagram; ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( ! empty( $pinterest ) ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $pinterest; ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( ! empty( $linkedin ) ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $linkedin; ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

I am trying to reduce any duplicate entry here, and make sure the items are removed from code if not filled out in the user profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually load them into an array:

```
$author_contact = array(
   'email'      => get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), 
   'telephone'  => get_the_author_meta( 'telephone' ),
   'twitter'    => get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ),
);
```

Once you have that created, you can iterate through it using a `foreach()` loop:

```
<ul class="author-contact">
<?php
foreach( $author_contact as $contact => $address ) {
   if( isset( $contact ) ) {
      echo '<li class="contact">' . $address . '</li>';
   }
}
?>
</ul>
```

What this code will do is go through all of those `get_author_meta()` values and store them in a single array. Then it will loop through them as the pair `$contact` & `$address`. So say it was `email` and the author's address was `author@site.com`. `$contact` would be `email` and `$adress` would be `author@site.com`.

Then it will test to see if there is a value given. So if this particular author does not have their telephone number or a Twitter address entered in, then the key would have null value. `isset()` will check to see if there is a value and if so, create the list item. If the value is `null` then it will simply skip that and move to the next key in the array.

Comment: Great Cedon! Needed a few code edits to make it work (won't let me amend your post).  Missing closed bracket after "isset... $contact", and missing semicolon after closed list tag. Thanks!

Comment: One last thing, I've just realised that this method leaves empty list items if the field is empty... Is there a way to remove them? eg. "Else echo '';" (didn't work).

Comment: I added the missing `)`. You could also try setting the `if()` condition to `if( $address != '' )`